# $[R(T)]^o$ $?!?!$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I was studying linear algebra(Linear Transformations) a day back and came across this notation and couldn't understand what it meant. Is it the $interior$ of the $Range$ of linear transformation $T$? What does that mean?

Comment: I've seen $R(T)$ used as the range of some operator $T$ (note that a linear transformation is simply an operator). But I'm not sure what that $^O$ business is... Sure it isn't a smudge on the page? ;D

Comment: Is it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29#Interior_operator

Comment: I don't know why the interior would be used here. With the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the interior of any subspace is either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\emptyset$ (in particular, this holds for $R(T)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is indeed linear algebra, then in my opinion
$$
R(T) = \text{ image of } T = \{w: \ \exists v:\ w=Tv\}
$$
is the image of $T$. And ${}^0$ denotes the annihilator:
If $T$ is a linear mapping from $V$ to $W$, then $R(T)=R(V)$ is a subspace of $W$, and its annihilator is
$$
[R(T)]^0=\{ f\in W^*: \ f(w) = 0 \ \forall w\in R(T)\},
$$
which is the set of all linear mappings $f\in W^*=L(W,K)$ from the dual space, that are zero on all elements of $R(T)$.

See e.g. [German wiki page - Annihilator](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_%28Mathematik%29) with the same notation $L^0$, the  [English wiki page - Annihilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Annihilators) with notation $L^\perp$.

hth